# No good can come from the [malicious] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, clean-up

[malicious](/questions/tagged/malicious) currently has **95** questions of which [**82** are open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bmalicious%5d%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3a0).  There is no tag wiki.

Almost all of the questions are "hey my site got hacked and someone inserted this code, what's it do and is it malicious?"  The questions have very little in common, the tag can't stand alone, and there's no reasonable way to define or clarify what really *is* malicious in a way that's on-topic.

In other words, [malicious](/questions/tagged/malicious) is malignant.  Thankfully, it's a curable disease.  If you feel like being a hero today:

- Questions that can not be salvaged to be on-topic and helpful should be closed.
- Questions that can be salvaged should be edited.

Please remember *not* to remove the tag from a closable question until it's actually closed.

Comment: [contain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contain) is going next. ~74 questions.

Comment: Burninate mode initiated!

Comment: Also can you make it in a synonym request [malicious] -> [wordpress]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Burned
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >                                                 [image]

Comment: We needed the tag alive to clean up those horrible questions.  :p

Comment: @Charles: 80% of them are now in the close vote queue.  Also, don't add a [burninate-request] if you don't want to burn the tag.  Oops.